# Unity 3D shoot and destroy enemy do not work

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 3d, game-physics

I have a Player who uses a weapon to shoot and destroy enemies. I have a code for a gun:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Gun : MonoBehaviour {

    float bulletSpeed = 60;
    public GameObject bullet;

void Fire(){
  GameObject tempBullet = Instantiate (bullet, transform.position, transform.rotation) as GameObject;
  Rigidbody tempRigidBodyBullet = tempBullet.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
  tempRigidBodyBullet.AddForce(tempRigidBodyBullet.transform.forward * bulletSpeed);
  Destroy(tempBullet, 5f);
}


    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
          Fire();
          
        }
    }
}
```

and the code for bullets:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Bullet : MonoBehaviour
{

 private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
 {
 if (other.tag == "Enemy")

    {
      Destroy(gameObject);
    }
  }
}
```

even though my enemy is tagged as 'enemy' and has a box collider triggered it doesnt disappear. The bullet prefab has rigidbody and sphere collider. Please help :)

Comment: Do you have trigger bool check on collider in inspector?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are telling the bullet to destroy itself. You probably rather wanted

```
private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    if (other.CompareTag("Enemy"))  
    {
        // Destroy the thing tagged enemy, not youself
        Destroy(other.gameObject);

        // Could still destroy the bullet itself as well
        Destroy (gameObject);
    }
}
```

Comment: `Collider other` contains collider data on which the bullet has hit right?

Comment: `other` is a `Collider` marked as `IsTrigger` that entered into the Collider attached to the bullet yes

Answer (score 5):

If you use Destroy(gameObject) you are destroying the bullet.

In order to destroy the enemy you should do a

`Destroy(other.gameObject)`

So you will destroy the object that actually triggered, the enemy

Comment: Sorry when I was writing the answer @derHugo had already answered. Accept his answer